# How does a class use a method defined in another class in Java?

Tags: java

How to use the `getvolume()` method defined by the `Box` class in the `boxweight` class? I know that I have to instantiate the Box class in order to use the method defined by it, but how?

```
class Box {
    private int lenght;
    private int breadth;
    private int height;
    int price;

    Box(int l, int b, int h) {
        lenght= l;
        breadth= b;
        height= h;
    }

    public Box(int p) {
        price= p;
    }

    double getvolume() {
        return lenght*height*breadth;
    }

    void setsize(int $l, int $b, int $h  ) {
        lenght= $l;
        breadth= $b;
        height= $h;
    }
}

public class boxclassdemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box mybox1=new Box(10,10,10);
        Box mybox2=new Box(5,5,5);
        Box mybox3=new Box(20);

        System.out.println(mybox1.getvolume());
        System.out.println(mybox2.getvolume());
        System.out.println(mybox3.price);
    }
}
```

The boxweight class:

```
public class boxweight  {
    int weight;
    int length,breadth,height;  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boxweight myboxx =  new boxweight();
        myboxx.weight= 25;
        myboxx.length=10;
        myboxx.breadth=20;
        myboxx.height=30;
    }
}
```

Comment: Create an instance of Box class and use it

Comment: you will need to define an object of the class Box and call the method to that instance

Comment: And you want to learn about java coding conventions. There are rules on how to name classes, methods and so on; and you don't seem to know them. For your actual question: that is like super basic knowledge; from the sort ... that well, you should not ask other people. You should turn to books and tutorials and **learn** about the foundations of Java; instead of relying on other people to explain them to you.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ can you please elaborate ?

Comment: @Jägermeister Why dont you just write exact solution instead of all that stuff. I know that i didn't followed java coding conventions.

Comment: @SrujanSujju That "stuff" is a polite information about how this site works. But it seems you did not get it, so again: this is not a site where you just order "help", and other people spend their free time to just provide that. For example, it is expected that you do prior research. Besides: you expect other people to help you; so you want to make that as easy as possible. Not following conventions simply makes it harder for other people to read your code. So, we shall help you; but you are not even willing to provide input in the best way possible?! So, why do you think we should help you?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer to your question, as well to many other questions you doubtlessly will have soon on [Oracle Java Tutorial on Object Creation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

```
As you know, a class provides the blueprint for objects; you create an object from a class. Each of the following statements taken from the CreateObjectDemo program creates an object and assigns it to a variable:

Point originOne = new Point(23, 94);
Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(originOne, 100, 200);
Rectangle rectTwo = new Rectangle(50, 100);

The first line creates an object of the Point class, and the second and third lines each create an object of the Rectangle class.
```

The same goes for actually using these, [the very next tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html):

```
Code that is outside the object's class must use an object reference or expression, followed by the dot (.) operator, followed by a simple field name, as in:

objectReference.fieldName
```

I recommend for you to either start reading these tutorials or get yourself a good java book, there's plenty out there.

Answer (score 0):

(By the way, the first letter of class name usually be upcast. 
If you use Eclipse or other IDE, it will help you create when you do the follow step.

`Box box = new Box(25, 10, 20, 30);`

Then,
`System.out.println(box.getvolume());`

Comment: Please take the time to better format your answer. Hint: vertical spacing (called paragraphs) typically make reading text easier. Then: you can't say from his code that he needs an import ...

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you want to use inheritance. If you define BoxWeight like this, note the '`extends Box`' after the class name:

```
public class BoxWeight extends Box {
    int weight;

    BoxWeight(int l, int b, int h, int w) {
        super(l, b, h);
        weight = w;
    }
}
```

Then you can treat a boxweight object as if it were a Box object, which means you can use it's public methods, like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BoxWeight myboxx =  new BoxWeight(10, 20, 30, 25);
    double volume = myboxx.getvolume();
}
```